# how to decrease value in the table2 with that operation in table1(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

now I am trying to decrease the value in the table2 with that operation in table1.

Here is table1 structure:

1. id_data_inserted
2. date
3. id_data
4. amount_of_inserted
5. id_room

table2 structure:

1. id_data
2. data_name
3. specification
4. amount
5. price

this question is part2 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100379/how-to-insert-data-to-table1-with-checking-field-from-table2-codeigniter-upda)

here is the GUI from table1(view table1):

[image]

and here is the GUI from table2(view table2):

[image]

I already tried to increase the amount value in the table2 when I input data from table1. For example, in the beginning, all of the data in the table2 have amount values is = 0 but if I want to increase the amount value in the table2 we need input data from table1 with input the amount_of_inserted. This mean,
if I insert data from table1 with the value of amount_of_inserted = 1 the amount values in the table2 now become 1 because it is increased, it's already solved. But now I want to try to decrease the amount values from table2 if I click the delete button in the GUI table1, for example if amount values from table2 = 1 (because it's already inserted in table1 with amount values = 1) then, if I delete this row in the table1, the amount values in table2 will decrease, now the amount values of table2 = 0.

Here is my code:

My_Data.php(Controller)

```
<?php
class My_Data extends CI_Controller
{
   public function delete_datatable1($id)
   {
      $where = array('id_data_inserted' => $id);
      $this->my_model->delete_data($where, 'table1');
      $this->my_model->decrease_value($where);
      redirect('admin\data\my_data\view_table1');
   }

   public function view_table1()
   {
      $data['table1'] = $this->my_model->view_data('table1')->result();
      $this->load->view('admin/data/v_table1', $data);
   }
}
```

My_Model.php(Model)

```
<?php
class My_Model extends CI_Model
{
   public function view_data($table)
   {
      return $this->db->get($table);
   }

   public function delete_data($where, $table)
   {
      $this->db->where($where);
      $this->db->delete($table);
   }

   public function decrease_value($id)
   {
      $qry1 = $this->db->query("select id_data from table1 where 
      id_data_inserted = '$id'");
      $qry2 = $this->db->query("select amount_of_inserted from 
      table1 where id_data_inserted = '$id'");
      $qry3 = $this->db->query("update table2 set amount = amount - 
      '$qry2' where id_data = '$qry1'");
      return $qry3;
   }
}
```

v_table1(View)

```
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($table1 as $tdata)
            {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $tdata->id_data_inserted ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tdata->date ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tdata->id_data ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tdata->amount_of_inserted ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tdata->id_room ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo anchor('admin\Data\my_data/edit_data/'.$tdata->id_data_inserted, 'Edit'); ?>
                        <span>|</span>
                        <?php echo anchor('admin\Data\my_data/delete_datatable1/'.$tdata->id_data_inserted, 'Delete'); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
```

but not working, the amount value from table2 not decrease if i delete data rows in table1.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are missing something. As of my knowledge your are checking with the query not with its values. So there wont exist any where data in database as query, cause of that no change is taking place. try to get its values

for example:

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;");

    $`row = $query->row(0, 'User');`

    echo $row->name; // access attributes

    echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class`:
```

i have rewritten your code as:

```
    $this->db->select('id_data,amount_of_inserted')
    ->where('id_data_inserted',$id);
$query=$this->db->get('table1');
foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
    $id_data = $row['id_data'];
    $amount_of_inserted = $row['amount_of_inserted'];
}

$qry3 = $this->db->query("update table2 set amount = amount - 
      '$amount_of_inserted' where id_data = '$id_data'");
```

Comment: Thank u for your help @A_Anwin, now it's succesfully decreased, and thx u for your information.